# Azure portal. Garbage Collector metrics for the .NET core 3.1 LTS

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are currently using Azure portal to host our cloud solution. By good tradition, we are use the old framework for our web services - .NET core 3.1.
Meanwhile .NET core 3.1 is a long term support (LTS) framework until December 12 2022.
[.NET and .NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

I don't know when we will migrate from .NET core 3.1 to .NET 5 or higher.

At the moment, there are still no Garbage Collector metrics for the .NET core 3.1 on the Azure portal.
Ticket from 2021 on the microsoft Q&A portal - [App Service metrics show no garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/221535/app-service-metrics-show-no-garbage-collection.html)

Does anyone know if this will be implemented? Are there specialists from the Azure portal here? What is a workaround to collect metrics for the .NET core 3.1? Can grafana collect these metrics (GC metrics) for .NET core 3.1 on the Azure portal?

Comment: Please refer [Monitoring Metrics of .Net Core](https://myeneryilmaz.medium.com/monitoring-metrics-of-net-core-web-api-project-using-prometheus-and-grafana-128c802f5bd3)

Comment: @HarshithaV just a middleware for request metrics, not a CLR metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the ***Garbage Collection metrics*** in Azure Portal for ***.NET Core 3.1*** Web App.
Please Check the below workaround

- Created .NET Core Web App in Visual Studio.
- In Solution Explorer, Double click on the Application Name .csproj file will be opened.
  In `.csproj` file , add the below line

```cs
 <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
```

Publish the App to Azure App Service

In ***Azure Portal*** => Your ***Web App*** => Select ***Metrics*** under ***Monitoring*** Section

- Click on Add Metric and add the metric Gen0, Gen1 and Gen2

[image]

***References taken from :***

[Memory management and patterns in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)